# dateTime return 1 day before week from today

Tags: php

How can I return only 1 day before 1 week from today with `dateTime`?

I did this:

```
if ($_POST['interval'] == 88) {

    $dayNumber = "7";
    $pid = 'P1W';
}

$now = new DateTime($dayNumber . " days ago");
$interval = new DateInterval($pid); // 1 Day interval
$period = new DatePeriod($now, $interval, $dayNumber);
```

This returning day before 1 week and today but + all days between which is not good.

Comment: Do you mean 6 days from today (1 week minus 1 day)?

Comment: No,i mean return only 1 day before 1 week,example today 15/07 thern return 08/07 day

Comment: That's what the period is, I think you want to use the sub method: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php

Answer (score 0):

looking for something like this, Let me know if it works for you

```
$dateString = "2016-07-15"; // for example
$minus6 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$dateString -7 days"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code is doind that: `$now = new DateTime('7 days ago');`

$now will returns '2016-07-08' from today (2016-07-15).

You dont need Interval and Period to return only one date.